# Deploying with github, git_discovery_across_filesystem not set

Tags: git, deployment

I've seen many threads and blog posts about my problem but none of them solved my problem, so I'll ask here if anyone has encountered the same problem.

I'm attempting to deploy my website via github. I have created a bare hub.git repo on the server, I push my local git repo to it, checked if it worked with a git log and everything was fine.

I then cloned this repo on the server in a repo called dev and made a virtual host for it and everything shows up fine.

I used to push from local to hub and then pull hub from dev and it worked fine. I wanted to automate this, I wanted to be able to push from local to hub and automatically pull hub from dev. So I created a post-update file in hub.git/hooks and put this in it :

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo
echo "***** updating on dev *****"
echo 
cd /../dev || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master
```

I then made sure that my post-update was executable with a

```
   chmod +x hooks/post-update
```

Went back to my local repo, changed a file

```
   git add .
   git commit -m "testing"
   git push origin
```

This message comes up

```
   remote : 
   remote : ***** updating on dev *****
   remote : 
   remote : fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /dev)
   remote : Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I checked and there is a .git in my dev directory and the HEAD hasn't been renamed or anything. However I do have a HEAD, a FETCH_HEAD and a ORIGIN_HEAD (don't know if that would change anything).

I'm not sure what the problem is here. The server is a gentoo x86 (if that might help at all).
Sorry if I'm just missing something obvious or if this isn't the place to post this.

Answer (score 0):

replacing `cd /../dev`  by `cd ../dev` should help.

If not, try `echo $(pwd)` to see where you are in the output